# SASS "Ampersand" and parent Selector

Tags: css, sass

I want to know it is possible to do something like this ( see example below ) in Sass with the Ampersand.

See example below.

```
.page-swup-2 {

    .page-surtitle {
        @include anim('opacity', 200ms, 500ms);
        opacity: 0;

        body.swup-animationInDone & {
            opacity: 1;
        }

    }

}
```

// Actual result

```css
body.swup-animationInDone .page-swup-2 .page-surtitle {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

// Expected result

```css
body.swup-animationInDone.page-swup-2 .page-surtitle {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `@at-root` => https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/at-root and `&` with interpolation syntax:

```
.page-swup-2 {
    .page-surtitle {
        @at-root body.swup-animationInDone#{&} {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Your new result:

```
body.swup-animationInDone.page-swup-2 .page-surtitle {
  opacity: 1;
}
```